# Trying to use Async and Await from different functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

While I thought I was using Async and Await keywords properly, it appears as though I am doing something wrong.

I am using PouchDB, which is a great Javascript database that syncs with CouchDB. PouchDB uses promises for many of its functions, and has native support for Async and Await.  As an example, to retrieve the basic information about a database, you would use the following code:

```
    db.info().then(function (info) {
  console.log(info);
})
```

I understand this, and it works.  But if I try and put this inside a function, and then call that function, things go haywire. And I'm sure it's me and not PouchDB that is the problem...

```
function getLocalDBInfo(db){

  try {
    db.info().then(function (info) {
      return info;
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("can't get local DB info: ", error);
  }
}

async function testing(db){
  try {
    var info=await getLocalDBInfo(db);
    await console.log("DB info=", info);
    await console.log("Doc count= ", info.doc_count);
  }
  catch(err){
    console.log("error=",err);
  }

  //info contains...
    //{"doc_count":0,"update_seq":0,"db_name":"kittens"}
}

testing(MY_db);
```

If I log `info` inside the `getLocalDBInfo` function, it eventually (ie. after the promise fulfills) logs `info` to the console.  But, the logs inside the `testing` function return immediately with `undefined`.  It makes sense to me that they are returning `undefined` because they are returning immediately, but I was trying to have them wait for `info` by using `async` and `await`.  Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `getLocalDBInfo` is not marked as async, plus you actually need to `return` something like `return await db.info();`

Comment: @crashmstr Thanks very much for the reply.  I didn't mark getLocalDBInfo as async because it uses the regular promise structure and, according to PouchDB, is a promise.  Maybe I was wrong?I think that info is the result of the promise, not the promise itself.  If I log info, it ultimately shows the resolved promise in the console so info ultimately results in something, but are you saying that returning the promise itself, as opposed to just the result, is the way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getLocalDBInfo() is not returning a promise, so you can't await for it.

with async/await you could:

```
async function getLocalDBInfo(db){
    try{
       return await db.info()
    } catch (err){
       console.log("can't get local DB info: ", error);
    }
}
```

you can also use [new promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: I've marked this as the solution, but several of the responses all say the same thing, which is to return a promise, and not the result of the promise.  A few responses suggested that I must mark the `getLocalDBInfo` function as `Async` but, in the end, that wasn't necessary and the only change required was to `return db.info()`.  I suspect it was not necessary to mark the `getLocalDBInfo` function as Async because the `db.info()` is already a promise via the PouchDB API, but I am happy to be corrected.

Comment: you're right, in the example I'm resolving db.info inside of getLocalDBInfo and returning a new promise, if you don't make getLocalDBInfo async you're just passing the db.info promise around

Comment: I did that so the error handling could take place in the wrapper function, as try catch blocks are triggered when promises resolve

Comment: Great stuff.  This makes sense to me.  Thank you for your responses. I'm trying to understand this stuff better (I've done several tutorials, looked at the spec, and done additional research and playing around with it) but I think I might still think too sequentially (which is probably why I prefer `Async/Await`).

Answer (score 1):

`getLocalDBInfo` generates a promise, attaches a callback to it, then returns `undefined`. It doesn't return the resolved promise and you can't await on an `undefined` (well, you can, but it won't do anything).

You neee to change `getLocalDBInfo` to actually `return` the promise.

Also, why do you have a `then` block with the signature `info => info`? All this will do is unwrap the async value and then wrap it again. You can omit the `then` callback entirely.

Similarly, are you sure you need to wrap the `db.info` call in a try/catch? I wonder if you might be intending to use a `promise.catch` here instead. The try/catch construct only grabs promise rejections when `awaiting` an expression.

Comment: Thank you for the reply which was helpful and, ultimately led to me getting things working. Forgive what is undoubtedly a really basic, embarrassingly simple question, but I thought that the purpose of the `.then` syntax was to wait for the resolved promise and then do something with that result. I then reasoned, incorrectly obviously, that if I put the `return` statement within the `.then` callback it would return the result of the promise (ie. `info`). Can you set me straight on this thinking? I know I'm missing something, but can't figure out what it might be.

Comment: @robertsmith So, when a promise is resolved with a value, `.then` maps that value into another promise. But you don't need to map the value, you can just await on the promise. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: Yes, I believe I do.  That makes sense.  It seems like I was doing twice what only needed to be done once. Correct?  Sorry, but one more question: if it maps into another promise, what would the harm be in returning that promise (other than inefficiency of course)?  Is that new promise what I was purporting to return by `return info`? I don't see how it could have been as it didn't work the way I had it.  Again, thank you for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value from the outer function `getLocalDBInfo`

```
function getLocalDBInfo(db) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.info()
      .then(info => resolve(info))
      .catch(err => reject(err))
  })
}
```